непонятная проблема с sstream c++
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map <string, string> mp;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string country, city, x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> country;
        getline(cin, city);
        stringstream iss(city);
    }
}

выдает ошибку "использование неполного типа stringstream не разрешено"

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
